# Get the status of a std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

Is it possible to check if a `std::future` has finished or not? As far as I can tell the only way to do it would be to call `wait_for` with a zero duration and check if the status is `ready` or not, but is there a better way?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Unless I'm mistaken, `valid` only checks if the future has a shared state (i.e. It returns `true` until `get` is called on the future).

Comment: So, if `get` has been called and returns the stored value, do you still want `true`?  (I'm not sure why this would be useful, since you can only get the value once.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis perhaps I am misunderstanding or misusing futures, but what I want is to know if the thread (or whatever is performing the calculation) is finished or not. The equivalent of Qt's [`QFuture::isFinished`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuture.html#isFinished) basically.

Comment: A wait with a zero timeout is how most APIs across many platforms deal with such a concept...  So much so that I would consider it the "standard" way of approaching the concept.  This makes me a bit puzzled at the notion of "a better way"...

Comment: @asveikau I was not aware this was a standard practice. It just feels odd to call a wait function when I do not wish to wait.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9094422/873025

Comment: If the future is empty, wait_for produces an ERROR

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You are correct, and apart from calling `wait_until` with a time in the past (which is equivalent) there is no better way.

You could always write a little wrapper if you want a more convenient syntax:

```
template<typename R>
  bool is_ready(std::future<R> const& f)
  { return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready; }
```

N.B. if the function is deferred this will never return true, so it's probably better to check `wait_for` directly in the case where you might want to run the deferred task synchronously after a certain time has passed or when system load is low.

Comment: wait_for doesn't mutate the future so the parameter could be declared as const.

Comment: Consider checking valid() first to avoid run time errors if get was already called or the future was never initialized.

Comment: Is wait_for(chrono::seconds(0)) guaranteed to return immediately or could it yield the control of the thread for a couple of milliseconds on some implementations? This would be quite important to know as a couple of milliseconds is a lot of time when coding a game...

Comment: @kynnysmatto, on some implementations it acquires a mutex lock to safely inspect the state of the future, so if that lock is contended (because another thread is making the state ready, or also checking for readiness) then it will block, and another thread could run, but on a good implementation the mutex should never be held for more than a few instructions, so not even a single millisecond. GCC's current implementation doesn't use a mutex at all, but the previous one did and making the state ready is done by swapping two pointers, so the mutex is only locked very briefly while that happens.

Comment: @JonathanWakely testing with g++ `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) f.wait_for(chrono::seconds(0));` takes 43ms of wall clock time.

Comment: @DanielKinsman, so not even a single millisecond then, as I said. And it's **much** faster once the future is ready: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KDfXPGpgg38jX0LT

Comment: A large part of that time is getting the current time. If you use `wait_until(chrono::system_clock::time_point::min())` you don't need the current time, and it's [faster](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z1arsDE7eHW9JrqJ). That optimisation is specific to GCC though, and for GCC 11 you'd need to use `steady_clock` instead of `system_clock` as we're about to change the clock that is used under the covers.

Comment: With the current dev sources for GCC (which will be GCC 11 next year) `f.wait_for(0)` is almost as fast as it is after the future is ready. Less than 100ns.

Answer (score 20):

There's an is_ready member function [in the works](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf) for std::future. In the meantime, the VC implementation has an _Is_ready() member.

Comment: Note that the _Is_ready() member function is NOT thread-safe. It accesses the _Ready flag of the associated state in an unguarded way. This is at least the case for VS2019 16.2.

Comment: lol, typical C++. Something is "in the works" in 2014 and in 2023 it's nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 13):

My first bet would be to call `wait_for` with a 0 duration, and check the result code that can be one of `future_status::ready`, `future_status::deferred` or `future_status::timeout`.

`valid()` will return `true` if `*this` refers to a shared state, independently of whether that state is *ready* or not. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Comment: cppreference has now been updated and states "checks if the future has a shared state". (Not sure if you want to remove your second paragraph or edit it, so I'll won't modify it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, `std::future` now has both a `wait()` and a `get()` method, which will wait until the future has a valid response, with the latter method waiting (blocking) and then returning a result when it is ready.

- cppreference: [wait()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait)
- cppreference: [get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get)

If you want to check if it's ready without blocking, then I've done the same as what David Rodríguez - dribeas suggested; call `wait_for` with a 0 (or maybe up to 10ms) duration, and check the result code that can be one of `future_status::ready`, `future_status::deferred` or `future_status::timeout`. How short the delay needs to be depends on your needs.

- cppreference: [wait_for()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for)
- cppreference: [std::future_status](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_status)