# How to determine whether a std::future has a value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

Note that this is different from calling `valid()`. `valid()` indicates whether the future has a valid shared state at all, however what I want to know is whether a value for the future has been set (i.e. via `std::promise::set_value`).

There's a `wait_for` method, however I don't want the calling thread to block at all, I just want to check for the presence of a value. Theoretically, I could call `wait_for` with a zero duration, but I don't know if it's actually the preferred way of doing this and I'm not sure what the expected behavior is when `wait_for` is called with a zero duration.

Comment: [Get the status of a std::future](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10890242/3953764)

Comment: Thanks! From various sources (including this answer) I pieced together that wait_for with zero duration should work.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of using std::future, is to be able to run a task asynchronously. Thus only call call get() on the future when you need the value, because the
thread blocks until the future is ready and then returns the value.

Comment: I don't think thats always true, what about when you are in an "eventual consistency" scenario?  You might not always want to block on a future.

Comment: you can wait on a future with a timeout