# Problem with std::async, and std::lock_guard - varying incremented values in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, stdasync

I have been experimenting with `std::async`. I wrote a (terribly inefficient) function that sums up all prime numbers up to a given limit.

Without `std::async` the function always gives the expected outcome as judged by a `ctest` unit test. Using `std::async` but no `std::lock_guard` / `mutex`, there is (as expected) a big deviation between the expected value and the calculated one. Using `std::lock_guard` / `mutex`, the outcome is still irreproducible and gives the correct outcome in around 50% of the tests, in the other 50% the value is off by 1-2 (e.g. 9151 instead of 9152).

I am debating if there is a problem because another bottle neck is introduced by my `isPrime(int)` function. Alternatively, I am thinking that the program (sometimes) terminates prematurely before the last thread has done its work.

In either case, I don't understand why the `std::lock_guard` does not seem to protect the variable count.

```cpp
// primeAsync.cc

#include <future>
#include <vector>

#include "primeAsync.h"
#include "prime.h"

// mutex for thread safety
static std::mutex s_PrimeMutex;

// handle to store futures
static std::vector<std::future<void>> s_Futures;

static void countPrimesHelper(int* count, const long long number);

// passes ctest every other time, count is off by 1-2 (e.g. 9151 instead of 9152)
int countPrimesAsync(const long long limit) {
    int count = 0;
    for(long i = 2; i < limit; ++i) {
        s_Futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, countPrimesHelper, &count, i));
    }
    return count;
}

// helper function for countPrimesAsync, std::async
static void countPrimesHelper(int* count, const long long number) {
    if(isPrime(number)) {
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_PrimeMutex);
        ++(*count);
    }
}
```

```cpp
// prime.cc

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// always passes ctest
bool isPrime(const long long n) {
    int mod;
    for(long long m = n - 1; m > 1; --m) {
        mod = n % m;
        if(mod == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// always passes ctest
int countPrimes(const long long limit) {
    int count = 0;
    for(long i = 2; i < limit; ++i) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: And where are you waiting for all futures in vector to finish?

Comment: Thread sanitizer [detects a data race here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1vaYY8MzW). You might have better symbol luck locally.

Comment: Your count variable is a local variable in a function that starts lots of threads and then exits.  So the count pointer being incremented by all those threads points to a variable no longer exists.  Your are lucky it worked at all.  Waiting for all the threads to finish before the count variable stops existing is the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the function to wait for all futures to finish before count is returned:

```
// now seems to pass ctest every time
int countPrimesAsync(const long long limit) {
    int count = 0;
    for(long i = 2; i < limit; ++i) {
        s_Futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, countPrimesHelper, &count, i));
    }

    for(long i = 0; i < s_Futures.size(); ++i) {
        s_Futures[i].wait();
    }

    return count;
}
```

That solutions passes the test!

Alternatively, I found the following solution to check the status of a future:

[Get the status of a std::future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890242/get-the-status-of-a-stdfuture)

Not sure which one is preferred (if any).

Thanks already though!

In line with François Andrieux, this solution also works and passes the `ctest`, does not require a static variable, and I think is more elegant than a second for loop:

```
// now seems to pass ctest every time
int countPrimesAsync(const long long limit) {
    // handle to store futures
    std::vector<std::future<void>> s_Futures;
    int count = 0;
    for(long i = 2; i < limit; ++i) {
        s_Futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, countPrimesHelper, &count, i));
    }
    s_Futures.clear(); 
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Note that a `std::future` returned by `std::async` has the property that its destructor will block until the associated `async` function has completed. So for example you can use `s_Futures.clear()`. I would also suggest you consider moving `s_Futures` to be a local variable inside `countPrimesAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing people haven't mentioned, is that atomic variables allow you to have a value that is accessed and written to by multiple threads without race conditions, and will do so much faster than a lock guard.

For example:

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<int> count;

static void countPrimesHelper(std::atomic<int>* count, const long long number) {
    if(isPrime(number)) {
        (*count) += 1;
    }
}
```

This is race-condition free, even with 1 million threads accessing count. It works by doing the increment as one operation that can't be accessed in an incomplete state. It also prevents your processor, if you have a recent one, from doing this in parallel. (Using a low-level lock instruction that lasts for one operation)

Here is more information on the atomic header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic

Comment: @François Andrieux I agree, I quickly added the atomic solution in ```countPrimesHelper```. The function still fails the test, I believe, even though atomic may be faster than a lock guard, the main problem I was facing was that the futures were not ready when the program terminated.

Comment: @iridiumcc Yes, this answer is a distinct improvement but does not solve the core problem.