# C++11 - Managing worker threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am new to threading in C++11 and I am wondering how to manage worker threads (using the standard library) to perform some task and then die off. I have a pool of threads `vector<thread *> thread_pool` that maintains a list of active threads.

Let's say I launch a new thread and add it to the pool using `thread_pool.push_back(new thread(worker_task))`, where `worker_task` is defined as follows:

```
void worker_task()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "Hello, world!\n"
}
```

Once the worker thread has terminated, what is the best way to reliably remove the thread from the pool? The main thread needs to run continuously and cannot block on a `join` call. I am more confused about the general structure of the code than the intricacies of synchronization.

**Edit:** It looks like I misused the concept of a pool in my code. All  I meant was that I have a list of threads that are currently running.

Comment: What's the purpose of a _thread pool_ if each thread only executes one task?

Comment: ftp://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html read this before you think about constructing your thread pool architecture.

Comment: That's not what "pool" means...

Comment: @nosid I simplified the situation for the sake of the question. The threads I am creating will not be as short as the worker_task function I showed above, and I need to be able to display what all the threads are working on at any given time. The thread_pool actually won't contain a list of thread objects, but will contain metadata associated with each thread.

Comment: @nosid OP never wrote that, it is a "pool of thread" not a "thread pool", OP also stated "to perform some task and then die off" which is a statement that suggests that OP is not interested in a "thread pool" approach anyway.

Comment: Related: [How to check if a std::thread is still running?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9094422/873025).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::thread::detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) to *"separate the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits."*

If each thread should make its state visible, you can move this functionality into the thread function.

```
std::mutex mutex;
using strings = std::list<std::string>;
strings info;

strings::iterator insert(std::string value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
    return info.insert(info.end(), std::move(value));
}

auto erase(strings::iterator p) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
    info.erase(p);
}

template <typename F>
void async(F f) {
    std::thread{[f] {
        auto p = insert("...");
        try {
            f();
        } catch (...) {
            erase(p);
            throw;
        }
        erase(p);
    }}.detach();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the detach function so I'll look into that. One question about your code though, how come the erase is inside a catch? Is f expected to throw an exception when it is completed?

Comment: @Chirag: `erase` should be invoked regardless how the function terminates. However, I missed the case of successful termination. It would be better to use RAII instead.