# Is it possible to know if a std::thread finished given its std::thread::id?

Tags: c++

I have a collection of `std::thread::id`, and I would like to know if the related `std::thread` has finished, for any of the `std::thread::id` in the collection.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a std::thread is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094422/how-to-check-if-a-stdthread-is-still-running)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is anything in `std::thread` that does what you are asking, but you could make all of your threads run in a wrapper function, and at the end of the wrapper function you add the thread id to some data structure, then check that data structure to see if a thread has finished.

Comment: 1) use a value as a mark of finish; 2) use std::async std::future std::promise rather than std::thread unless you have a very strong reason.

Comment: I do not have access to the thread, only to the thread id.

Here is what I intend to do: https://pastebin.com/40CQxiNf

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is probably an XY question. Why do you care whether the thread has finished or not? Are you sure you don't really care whether some particular task is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out how:

```
struct logger {
enum level : int16_t { debug = 0, info = 1, warn = 2, error = 3, fatal = 4 };

~logger() {
    write_all();
}

logger & operator()(level p_level) {
    add(true)
            << "[" << get_level(p_level) << "]"
            << "[" << std::time(NULL) << "]"
            << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] ";
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
logger & operator << (const T & p_val) {
    add() << p_val;
    return *this;
}
private:

struct at_thread_end {
  at_thread_end (std::function<void (std::thread::id)> p_callback
                 , std::thread::id p_id)
      : m_callback(p_callback)
      , m_id(p_id){}

  at_thread_end(at_thread_end && p_at_thread_end)
      : m_callback(std::move(p_at_thread_end.m_callback))
      , m_id(std::move(p_at_thread_end.m_id)) {}

  at_thread_end & operator=(at_thread_end && p_at_thread_end) {
      m_callback = std::move(p_at_thread_end.m_callback);
      m_id = std::move(p_at_thread_end.m_id);
      return *this;
  }

  ~at_thread_end() {
      m_callback(m_id);
  }

private:
  std::function<void (std::thread::id)> m_callback;
  std::thread::id m_id;
};

typedef std::map<std::thread::id, std::stringstream> streams;

void on_thread_end(std::thread::id p_id) {
    std::cout << "thread " << p_id << " ended" << std::endl;
    streams::iterator _ite = m_streams.find(p_id);
    if (_ite != m_streams.end()) {
        write(_ite->second.str());
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(m_mutex_streams);
        m_streams.erase(_ite);
    }
}

std::stringstream & add(bool p_clean = false) {
    std::thread::id _id  = std::this_thread::get_id();
    streams::iterator _ite = m_streams.find(_id);
    if (_ite != m_streams.end()) {
        if (p_clean) {
            write(_ite->second.str());
            _ite->second.str("");
        }
        return _ite->second;
    }


    using std::placeholders::_1;
    thread_local at_thread_end
            _at_thread_end(std::bind(&logger::on_thread_end, this, _1)
                           ,_id);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(m_mutex_streams);
    m_streams[_id] = std::stringstream();
    return m_streams[_id];
}

std::string get_level(level p_level) {
    switch (p_level) {
    case level::debug:
        return "DEB";
    case level::info:
        return "INF";
    case level::warn:
        return "WAR";
    case level::error:
        return "ERR";
    case level::fatal:
        return "FAT";
    }
    return "LEVEL UNKNOW";
}

void write(const std::string & p_str) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(m_mutex_write);
    if (p_str.size()) {
        std::cout << p_str << std::endl;
    }
}

void write_all() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock(m_mutex_streams);
    streams::iterator _end = m_streams.end();
    for (streams::iterator _ite = m_streams.begin(); _ite != _end; ++_ite) {
        write(_ite->second.str());
    }
}

streams m_streams;
std::mutex m_mutex_streams;
std::mutex m_mutex_write;

};
```

You can look at a full example at https://pastebin.com/z2HrF70U

Answer (score 1):

Not in a portable fashion. Generally you will have to have the threads set a flag to indicate the actual condition you want to test.