# C++ async programming, how to not wait for future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++17

I'm trying to learn async programming in C++. In Python, we have `await`, with which we can resume a function from that point, but in C++ `future` waits for the results and halts the next line of code. What if we don't want to get the result, but instead continue to the next line of code? How can I do this?

Comment: You need a coroutine/fiber library.

Comment: Unclear. Post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`std::future::wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) to check if the task has completed execution, *e.g.*:

```
if (future.wait_for(100ms) == std::future_status::ready) {
    // Result is ready.
} else {
    // Do something else.
}
```

The [Concurrency TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency) includes [`std::future::is_ready`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/is_ready) (may be included in C++20), which is non blocking. If it gets included in the standard, usage will be something like:

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, my_func);

while (!f.is_ready()) {
    /* Do other stuff. */
}

auto result = f.get();

/* Do stuff with result. */
```

Alternatively, the Concurrency TS also includes [`std::future::then`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then), which I interpret can be used *e.g.* as:

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, my_func)
    .then([] (auto fut) {
        auto result = fut.get();
        /* Do stuff when result is ready. */
    });

/* Do other stuff before result is ready. */
```

Also see: [How to check if a std::thread is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9094422/873025)

Comment: could you write a demo code using concurrency TS , to show its implementation.

Answer (score 4):

> future waits for the results and halts the next line of code

This is only true when you invoke `.get()` or when the future is being destroyed. You can run multiple tasks in parallel with `std::future`:

```
std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo);
auto res0 = bar();
auto res1 = f.get();
```

In the example above, `bar` and `foo` will run in parallel.

---

If you want to attach asynchronous continuations to an existing future, currently you cannot do that with `std::future`.

`boost::future` supports non-blocking `.then(...)`, `.when_all(...)`, and `.when_any(...)` continuations. These are proposed for standardization in ["Extensions for concurrency"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency).

There's also a ["Coroutines" TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4723.pdf) that aims to introduce resumable functions and `co_await`/`co_yield`.

Unsurprisingly, `boost` also provides a coroutine library that can be used today to implement resumable functions.

Comment: why dont they just copy paste boost into the C++ standard library, because everytime boost comes up with something good, the C++ standard library comes with a bootleg implementation of the same thing