# Check if an std::thread finished execution without std::thread::join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094422/how-to-check-if-a-stdthread-is-still-running) stack-overflow question about this but it is 11 years old and I was wondering if there's a better way to do this as the question was posted in C++11 times.

There is `std::thread::joinable()` but the problem is that even if the thread finished executing, it will still be marked as `joinable`, if it hasn't been joined with `std::thread::join()`.

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined
> is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore
> joinable.
> [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable)

I could use an `std::atomic<bool> threadFinished = false;` and set it to `true` in the thread right before it finishes (this is mentioned in the answer of the stack-overflow question I mentioned at the beginning of this question).

Something like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> threadFinished = false;

std::thread myThread([&threadFinished]() {
    std::this_thread::wait(1000);
    threadFinished = true;
});

while (true) {
    if (threadFinished) {
        // Thread finished executing (note: myThread.joinable() is still true)
        break;
    }
}

myThread.join();
```

But this seems very unclean and unscalable, especially if you have many return points in the thread. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: "*But this seems very unclean and unscalable [...]*" - in this case I would inherit from `std::jthread` privately and add the functionality you desire to be handled internally by your class.

Comment: So there isn't any built-in functionality for this?

Comment: Why do you need that? If you want to wait until the thread is finished, then just join it, that's exactly what `join` does.

Comment: I think the value returned by `std::thread::get_id` might give you that information.  Worth trying that, at any rate.

Comment: @PaulSanders `std::thread::get_id` returns an id if its joinable, otherwise a default constructed instance

Comment: OK, well, that sounds promising.  But, to me, the question is: what does it return after the thread terminates?

Comment: No, there isn't any built-in way to do this, because it seems like it would not be possible to implement it in a portable way that would introduce no overhead. I am also a fan of adding as much as possible into the standard library, but C++ evolves in a different way.

Comment: I fail to see what concern you're trying to address.   Your thread function is (atomically) setting `threadFinished` to `true` immediately before it terminates.   Your other thread is waiting for `threadFinished` to be `true` and then calling `myThread.join()`.    Since `myThread.join()` will wait for `myThread` to complete, all of your machinery is just adding additional complication but achieving no more.

Comment: As you've observed, `joinable` has nothing to do with whether a thread has completed. It tells you whether a call to `join` is valid; you can't `join` a default-constructed thread and you can't `join` a thread that 's been `detach`ed and you can't `join` a thread that's already been `join`ed. That's what `joinable` tells you.

Comment: @Peter This is just a part of the code I'm using. There is more functionality in the loop than I put in the example.

Comment: If your function has many returns, add a wrapper first in the function: `struct s { std::atomic<bool>& b; ~s() { b = true; }} setter{threadFinished};`

Comment: Minor point: `if (threadFinished.load())` can be written `if (threadFinished)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this seems very unclean and unscalable, especially if you have
> many return points in the thread. Is there a better way to accomplish
> this?

To fix the unclean problem: RAII

```
struct ThreadFinishedSignaler
{
    ~ThreadFinishedSignaler(){ threadFinished = true; }
}
```

then in the thread:

```
ThreadFinishedSignaler sig;
doWork();
if(something)
    stopWorking(); // automatically sets true with destructor
doSomeWork();
// or here, automatically again, once the scope is gone
```

To fix the scalability: Have multiple atomics or mutexes working in parallel, 1 per thread:

```
struct NonFalseSharingMutexLock
{
    std::mutex mut;
    char augmentation[CacheLineSize - sizeof(std::mutex)];
}
```

then in the main thread:

```
NonFalseSharingMutexLock locks[numThreads];
```

finally in worker threads:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(locks[myThreadId]);
// change stuff
```

If main thread is not supposed to check an array of states, then you can combine the results as a "graph" with every 2 thread combining their results into 1 then other 2 threads do same, then 2 results combined into 1, ... like a graph or tree with no thread checking more than 2 results (less locking contention).

If the work done by each thread is big enough, you can simply use atomic integer:

In main thread:

```
std::atomic<int> numThreadsWorking = 32;
```

In worker threads:

```
struct ThreadFinishedSignaler
{
    ~ThreadFinishedSignaler(){ numThreadsWorking--; }
}

ThreadFinishedSignaler sig;
// exit anywhere, it just destructs and decrements automatically
```

when numThreadsWorking reaches zero, all work is complete.

Answer (score 2):

The interface of `std::future` provides you with possibility to both obtain the result and checking if it's finished by inspecting results of `wait` member functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task{ []() {
        for(auto i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 256 });
        }
        std::cout << "The task is done!\n";
    } };
    auto future = task.get_future();
    std::thread{ std::move(task) }.detach();
    while(future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 512 }) != std::future_status::ready) {
        std::cout << "Waiting for the result...\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```